# Python перехват текста консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Можно ли как- то просто перехватить вывод консоли? Т.е. мне нужно копировать, перенаправить или проделать иные действия чтобы  я мог работать с этим текстом( мне нужно просто перенаправлять его в форму в программе). Вроде как пишут с работой через файл ,но мне кажется это слишком сложным решением , может есть проще?

Comment: посмотрите subprocess, может это поможет.

Comment: Вывод консоли другой программы или своего скрипта изнутри?

Comment: @gil9red, моей программы все что она выводит , через print ,ошибки и т.д. Просто чтобы вывод программы выводился в нужном мне месте .

Answer (score 3):

Используйте модуль [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    print('123')
    print('abc')

s = f.getvalue()
print(s)
# 123
# abc
```

Еще пример с ручной ловлей исключения и перенаправления в `stderr`:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr
import io
import sys
import traceback

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f), redirect_stderr(f):
    try:
        print('123')
        print('abc')
        1 / 0
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)

s = f.getvalue()
print(s)
# 123
# abc
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File ..., line 18, in <module>
#     1 / 0
# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

**PS.**

Для перехвата `stderr` - `redirect_stderr`

Comment: спасибо, работает, но корректно из модуля . У меня немного сложнее -  я вызываю тесты через cmd pytest команды. Эти выводы в pycharm я вижу, а обренув метод запуска тестов не дало плодов( наверное и ожидаемо). Можно ли как-то такой вариант перехватить, или оборачивать каждый модуль теста?

Comment: Если из py кода тесты вызовите, обернув это `with redirect_stdout(f)` то получится, иначе вызывайте через subprocess и у него считывайте данные. Еще можно перенаправить средствами консоли поток вывода в файл через `>`. И возможно pytest умеет в файл выводить (я с ним не работал, просто предположение)

Comment: @gli9red, Спасибо за Ваши ответы, но пока не получается. Конструкция в главном файле такая :

Comment: self.f =  io.StringIO() , объявлен в инициализации 

 `with redirect_stdout(self.f), redirect_stderr(self.f):
            try:
                 os.system('cd all_tests & py -m pytest ' + x + ' -s -v')  # --run_number=1
             except:
                print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
  s = self.f.getvalue()
         self.log_text.insert(END, s + '\nx')`

Но пока обошел неправильным способом - у pytests есть команда --junitxml=logggGG.txt которая выгружает весь лог, но в xmk формате.

Comment: @sank, раз используйте `system`, то может быть вам больше подойдет `subprocess`, примеры с получением вывода: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6e0406151d57a24fdd7d5cdb4aecc551e8017d3c/subprocess_example/print_java_version.py), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c4ef2f1636f7d75b87807e858ea1eea6116df773/subprocess_example/ipconfig.py), [3](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dfb7ca2766460633aa62e1363c751fd893b08853/subprocess_example/run_and_input_text__num_sum/main.py)